# How to include milliseconds in a formatted date string?

Tags: java, android, date, time

Hi I am coding the following:

```
String sph=(String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss_SSS", new java.util.Date());
```

I want the current date and time and milliseconds

what it gives me is:

```
2011-09-01_09-55-03-SSS
```

The SSS is not converting back to milliseconds...

Does anyone know why and what should it be to get the milliseconds in 3 position?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 22):

Use the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss_SSS");
String dateString = formatter.format(new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: Note that I have changed "hh" to "HH", to display hour in a 24-hour format. Use "hh" if you need 12-hour format

Comment: While this Answer was correct when posted, the classes used here are now outmoded by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime          // Represent a moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone).
.now()                 // Capture current moment. Better to pass optional argument for `ZoneId` (time zone). Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.format(               // Generate a `String` with text in a custom formatting pattern.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-SSS" )
)                      // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 2018-08-26_15-43-24-895

## `Instant`

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Instead use the java.time classes.

If you want the date-time in UTC, use the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. This class holds nanosecond resolution, more than enough for milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
String output = instant.toString();
```

That [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) method uses the [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) formatter which prints 0, 3, 6, or 9 digits in the decimal fraction, as many as needed appropriate to the actual data value.

In Java 8 the current moment is captured only up to milliseconds but a new implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) in Java 9 may capture up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). So truncate to milliseconds if that is your requirement. Specify your desired truncation by a [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) as implemented in [`ChronoUnit.MILLIS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MILLIS).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want a specify time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-08-26T19:43:24.895621Z

```
Instant instantTruncated = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS );
```

> instantTruncated.toString(): 2018-08-26T19:43:24.895Z

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
String output = zdt.toString();
```

> 2018-08-26T15:43:24.895621-04:00[America/Montreal]

Again if you want other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter`.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

If you want to force three digits for milliseconds, even if the value is all zeros, specify a custom formatting pattern using `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-SSS" ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 2018-08-26_15-43-24-895

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same format with [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)